# Why is this dynamic array giving me the wrong output?

Tags: c++, pointers, debugging, dynamic-arrays

so I have this block of code that is supposed reviews for movie titles by stars (1-10) and a review amount that determines the size of the dynamic array I believe. but it's outputting the wrong number

```
void Movie::SetStars(const int* _stars, int _numReviews) {

    // Allocate array and deep copy
    mStars = new int[_numReviews];

    for (int i = 0; i < _numReviews; ++i) {
        // Cap reviews between 1-10
        if (_stars[i] > 10)
        {
            mStars[i] = 10;
        }
        else if (_stars[i] < 0)
        {
            mStars[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            mStars[i] = _stars[i];
        }
    }

    // Set the number of reviews
    mNumReviews = _numReviews;
}
```

This is the block of code that gets the average of all the reviews

```
float Movie::GetAverage() const {
    float total = 0;

    // Sum up the review scores
    for (int i = 0; i < mNumReviews; ++i)
        total += mStars[i];

    // Return the average
    return (float)total / mNumReviews;
}
```

It is supposed to output this: [Correct Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duqjo.png) but instead it Outputs this: [Incorrect Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZmnb.png)

If you'll like to see the whole page of code for this specific section it looks like this:
[Movie.cpp block of code](https://codeshare.io/50WdRv)

If you want to see my Movie class it looks like this:[Movie.h class](https://codeshare.io/2EYKdv)

Any clues or actual corrections would be of great help as to why it's showing that instead of the actual output.

Comment: You intialized every movie with the same array and took the average of the same array what do you expect??

Comment: Please paste relevant code into the question. You need to show the code that calls this function as well.

Comment: I suggest you should provide us with a minimal reproducible example to reproduce the issue. So, I could help you.